# Dual Australian/New Zealand citizenship with only Australian passport

Tags: dual-nationality

I am an Australian living in New Zealand and was recently granted New Zealand citizenship. However I only have an Australian passport.  Can I travel freely between Australia and New Zealand on my Australian passport?

Comment: Without a New Zealand passport, it will be up to you to prove you have a right to enter New Zealand.  It would be in your best interests to get a New Zealand passport to make this less time consuming and easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll be aware of the reciprocal arrangements between Australia and New Zealand that allow for essentially unrestricted travel between the two countries for their citizens, so in practical terms, yes, you can travel on your Australian passport.

However, if you do so you'll be admitted to New Zealand as an Australian citizen. With the current Australian stance on admitting NZ citizens it is possible that the NZ government may change arrangements for Australian citizens in the future.

You have two options if you wish to be admitted to New Zealand as a New Zealand citizen: apply for an endorsement in your Australian passport (details [here](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/my-situation-has-changed/live/im-now-a-new-zealand-citizen-but-travel-on-my-old-passport)), or apply for a New Zealand passport (details [here](https://www.govt.nz/browse/nz-passports-and-citizenship/passport-application/)).

Comment: Did Australia change their stance on NZ citizens recently?

Comment: @JonathanReez This user deleted their account, so it's unlikely they will ever see this comment. It might be worth a quick internet search and possibly a new question.

Comment: @JonathanReez The Australian government has become increasingly protectionist with respect to immigration over recent years. What used to be a fairly balanced arrangement has become somewhat one-sided. NZ citizens have the right to settle, work and pay taxes in Australia, but no right to any of the social benefits or healthcare unless they become Australian citizens. Recently Aus has taken to deporting criminals of NZ citizenship for sometimes fairly minor crimes and regardless of local ties...(more)

Comment: ...([see here](https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/110135771/australian-man-to-be-deported-to-nz-despite-never-having-set-foot-in-the-country)). There is a small but growing minority in NZ who would like to see the situation balance by action on the NZ side. Some politicians favour this.